# Cambiar el orden de Tabindex / Tabulación en un JFrame

Tags: java, apache-netbeans

### Tengo una formulario (Jframe) en Java Net Beans 13. Quiero cambiar el orden de tabulación del formulario cuando el usuario quiera: Agregar un nuevo registro y modificar. En C# lo que hacia era esto:

### this.txnom.tabindex =1;

¿Cómo sería lo anterior en Jframe? Es decir, lo quiero hacer según sea el caso (el orden el tabindex).

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si alguien le sirve, yo hice lo siguiente:

```
public void Ordenobjetosparaagregar(){ // ordena el tabindex de los objetos.
     try{
         this.setFocusTraversalPolicy((new Component[]{this.txtNomEnf, this.txtDescripEnf, this.btnGuardar, this.btnCancelar, this.btnSalir}));
     }         //Aquí ordeno, cuando el usuario pulsa Agregar / Nuevo registro. Prepara el orden de Tab para que al usuario le sea más fácil desplazarse en el Jframe.
     catch(Exception e){        
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al ordenar Tab index al Agregar:"+ e.toString());
     }
 }
 public void Ordenarobjetosmodificar(){
    try {
       this.setFocusTraversalPolicy((new Component[]{this.txtNomEnf, this.txtDescripEnf, this.btnGuardar, this.btnCancelar, this.btnSalir}));
    }//Aquí ordeno, cuando el usuario pulsa Modificar registro. Prepara el orden de Tab para que al usuario le sea más fácil desplazarse en el Jframe.
    catch(Exception e){        
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al ordenar Tab index al Modificar:"+ e.toString());
     }
 }
```

Esto lo puse para darle orden al "tab index". Cabe aclarar, que no soy experto. Disculpen, que no pueda dar grandes detalles técnicos. En fin, espero que para alguien que va empezando en Java como su servidor, le sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y dale formato al código, además de explicar brevemente su funcionamiento. También modifica tu pregunta: _netbeans_ no tiene nada que ver aquí con el problema en cuestión. Lee [answer], [ask], y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Por último: [_No uses firmas, taglines o saludos._](/help/behavior) (y relacionado: [Saludar o no saludar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4283)).